# I can only get 1/4 tests passing

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling

Implement the showCustomers function so that it renders customers as list items. The first argument to the function, customers, is an array of objects with the name and email properties. The second argument to the function, targetList, is an unordered HTML list to which each customer should be added as a separate list item.

The name and email properties should be added as two paragraphs inside the list item. At first, the email paragraph element should not be present in the DOM. The email paragraph element should be added to the DOM after the name is clicked, and it should be removed from the DOM when the name is clicked again.

```
function showCustomers(customers, targetList) {
    var ul = document.getElementById('customer');

    for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var paraName = document.createElement("p");
        var nameNode = document.createTextNode(customers[i]['name']);
        paraName.appendChild(nameNode);

        var paraEmail = document.createElement('p');
        var emailNode = document.createTextNode(customers[i]['email']);
        paraEmail.appendChild(emailNode);
        li.appendChild(paraName);
        li.appendChild(paraEmail);
        targetList.appendChild(li);

        paraName.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            let x = e.target.parentElement;
           x.removeChild(x.childNodes[1]);
        })
    }
}

document.body.innerHTML = `
<div>
  <ul id="customers">
  </ul>
</div>
`;
let customers = [{name: "John", email: "john@example.com"},
                 {name: "Mary", email: "mary@example.com"}];
showCustomers(customers, document.getElementById("customers"));

let customerParagraph = document.querySelectorAll("li > p")[0];
if(customerParagraph) {
  customerParagraph.click();
}
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

I have customer names that are rendered correctly correct. But Clicking customer names shows email and clicking customer names again hides email is wrong.

**Output**

```
 <div>
   <ul id="customers">
   <li><p>John</p></li><li><p>Mary</p><p>mary@example.com</p></li></ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try below:
```

```
function showCustomers(customers, targetList) {
  var ul = document.getElementById('customer');

  for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var paraName = document.createElement("p");
    var nameNode = document.createTextNode(customers[i]['name']);
    paraName.appendChild(nameNode);

    li.appendChild(paraName);
    targetList.appendChild(li);

    paraName.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        let x = e.target.parentElement;
        if (x.childNodes.length == 1) {
          for (var j = 0; j < customers.length; j++) {
            if (e.target.innerHTML == customers[j]['name']) {
              var paraEmail = document.createElement('p');
              var emailNode = document.createTextNode(customers[j]['email']);
              paraEmail.appendChild(emailNode);
                x.appendChild(paraEmail);
            }
          }
      } else {
        x.removeChild(x.childNodes[1]);
      }
    })
  }
}
```